# WCF - regenerate client code from interface contract

Tags: c#, wcf, code-generation

I have quite simple WCF service and its client - both reside in my application.
At the moment interface used for WCF contract consist of 3 methods, and according to MSDN I generated client code for it using svcutil.exe CLI.
But now I added one more method. And I wonder - is there a simpler way to regenerate client code (probably directly in VisualStudio) using doing less actions for this operation?

Comment: what version of VS are you using? I think that in the more recent versions, you can right-click your web project in the solution explorer and select "WCF configuration" for a nice window.

Comment: I am using VS 2013 and I don't have web project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on your Services References and select the service you'd like to regenerate code for. Then click Update Service Reference. Then you're done.

[image]
[image]

Update after re-reading the question I realized its possible you don't know how to import WCF Services.
Here is how its done:

[image]
[image]

Update as per comments:

There are two workarounds for this, The first is to run the application outside of your IDE and then go into your IDE to import it.

The second one is to create a proxy client that implements your service contract. When you are using the client proxy you can right click on the interface and select an option to implement the interface. Assuming that the set up is done correctly, if you make a change to the ServiceContract you can then go to your proxy class and just click implement interface which will update your proxy class. by doing this you bypass the svc utility completely; however, you have significantly more control over your development. You need to work with DLLs to accomplish this; however, it works like a charm. [Here](https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfPipeExample) is an example though I doubt you need one I'll just leave it for the sake of completeness. Use [this example](https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfDuplexPipeExample) for duplexes

Comment: I don't really have a web service, I am hosting my WCF service inside my WPF application when it is running. But anyway thank you for pointing out to these menus!

Comment: As long as you have the URI and its a WCF service you should be able to do this with it.

Comment: But I have to run my app to generate client code from it. And while app is running - code cannot be changed =). Am I missing something here?

Comment: More then that, WCF service has an interface with methods marked [OperationContract]. It is quite strange that I need to run it to generate my own client. It is ok when service is other application, and probably not your code at all, but not in my case.

Comment: @DarkDeny not sure how much it'll help you; however, I added to possible workarounds.